# The composer autoload went wrong, what's going on here?

Tags: php, composer-php

Composer version 1.6.3

I only performed：

```
composer require "hieu-le/active:~3.5"
```

I installed an extension package, but the fact was unexpected and here the error:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/Projects/cunzai$ composer require "hieu-le/active:~3.5"
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing hieu-le/active (3.5.1): Downloading (100%)
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::addClassMap() must be of the type array, integer given, called in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php on line 760 and defined in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:92

(1)phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php(760): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->addClassMap(1)

(2)phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php(303): Composer\Autoload\AutoloadGenerator->getStaticFile('c4e4dd9af67a9f1...','/home/vagrant/P...', '/home/vagrant/P...', '/home/vagrant/P...', 50600)

(3)phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php(302): Composer\Autoload\AutoloadGenerator->dump(Object(Composer\Config),Object(Composer\Repository\InstalledFilesystemRepository),Object(Composer\Package\RootPackage), Object(Composer\Installer\InstallationManager), '/home/vagrant/P...', true)

(4)phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/ in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 92
```

After the error, I also tried to install another extension package. The fact is also wrong. So I'm sure it's not an extension package. The Laravel framework and the composer can't be the cause of the error, but I can't think of a place. I hope There are grateful solutions posted to this problem.

**composer.json:**

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "hieu-le/active": "~3.5",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "mews/captcha": "~2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "~3.1",
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
        "symfony/thanks": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the error message in text form, please?

Comment: Sorry, it looks a bit messy. This is the problem I revised.

Comment: Does https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5707 help?

Comment: Please share content of your `composer.json`.

Comment: I updated the problem and added `composer.json` to the problem

Comment: It seems like you sent this url, and the solution they discussed was to discard `NFS`, but without `NFS`, it was super slow to access the site.

Comment: According to the solution of the github.com/composer/composer/issues/5707, to solve this problem temporarily, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked for me was:

In `composer.json`, change the version of streams-platform to `"anomaly/streams-platform": "1.3.219",`, and add all of these lines to the bottom of the "require" section:

```
"teamtnt/laravel-scout-tntsearch-driver": "3.0.6",
"teamtnt/tntsearch": "1.3.1",
"michelf/php-markdown": "^1.8"
```

Then run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

I'm using Laravel Homestead Vagrant on Virtualbox on Windows 10.

I used Git Bash to alternately run `composer update` directly in my project folder on Windows and then also after using SSH to get into that same project folder within the Ubuntu virtual machine.

My Homestead.yaml file uses `type: "nfs"`.